# Как сделать событие Jquery на блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один блок, закрывался другой(тот который был открыт ранее). А так же, чтобы блок закрывался и при нажатии на самого себя. Заранее спасибо. Есть код:

```
if (screen.width <= 991) {
    $(".reviews-tab-items-content").unbind(); 
    $(".reviews-tab-items-content").on('click',function(e){
        console.log('ttttttttttttttww');
        $(this).find(".hidden-text").slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (screen.width <= 991) {
  var toggle = 0;
  $('#block1').on('click', function() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
      $('#block2').fadeOut();
      toggle++;
    } else if (toggle == 1) {
      $('#block1').fadeOut();
      toggle = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#block1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">Click Me</div>

<div id="block2"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но ваш скрипт почему то не работает(

Comment: Уберите условие срабатывания `if (screen.width <= 991)`

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin Всё равно не работает

Comment: @Владислав Малышко сложно объяснить без html кода, мой пример работает.